# Looping through an Array in Php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can't seem to figure this out. I struggle so badly with arrays. I am trying to get the data out of this array and keep getting errors.

I tried using this code below and several other attempts and failed miserably. What's the best way to remember how to do this? Everytime I don't code Php for a couple months I seem to forget everything...

```
  foreach( $data as $key) { 
            foreach( $key as $value => $sum) {
              echo $sum;
            } 
        }





Array
    (
        [result] => OK
        [data] => Array
            (
                [destination] => 
                [tracking] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [loc] => Array
                                    (
                                        [city] => 
                                        [territory] => ME
                                        [country] => US
                                    )

                                [desc] => Delivered
                                [stamp] => 1384977300
                                [time] => 11/20/13 11:55 am
                                [locStr] => ME, US
                                [geo] => Array
                                    (
                                        [lat] => 45.253783
                                        [lon] => -69.4454689
                                    )

                            )
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I'm just trying to loop through this Array. I know, newbie question but I'm not much of a developer but I'm trying to learn. I mostly do design work and some frontend JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterate through tracking?

```
if ($arr['result'] == "OK") {

  for ($i=0; $i < count( $arr['data']['tracking'] ); $i++) {
    // do stuff with $arr['data']['tracking'][$i]
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, not sure why...   I also was trying this based on another thread but getting bad results:                foreach($data['data']['tracking'][0] as $arr) {
 echo $arr['desc'];
 echo $arr['time'];
 }

Comment: Right on target, I just got it working. Thanks alot for the help, much appreciated, I'm on the right track now.

Answer (score 1):

In php there are basically two different type of arrays. key/value based array and element based array. 
An element based array is

```
$arr = array("a", "b", "c");
echo $arr[0]; //  prints a
echo $arr[2]; //  prints c

   //  hash - k/v array
   $arr = array("monkey" => "banana", "chicken" => "egg");
   echo $arr["monkey"]; //  prints banana

   //  combination 
  $arr = array( array("monkey" => array("banana", "water")));
  echo $arr[0]["monkey"][1]; // prints water
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I think I made this problem way harder than it was but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is not wrong. you have three dimensional array. you have only two foreach. you have to loop within a loop within a loop. and if you try to echo an array Ofcourse you will have an error so you should check first if that output is an array or not.